# Why does my program not print the initials of a name? (CS50 Initials Program)

Tags: c, arrays, initializer-list, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
int i=0;
int x=0;
int n=0;

    argv[i]=GetString()
    printf("%c", toupper(argv[i][0]));
    for (x=0, n=strlen(argv[i]); x<n; x++)
    {
        printf("%c", toupper(argv[i+1][0]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The code compiles but does not print the initials of a name entered by the user. For instance, `John Smith: JS`. I receive a segmentation fault instead.

This program is initials.c for CS50.

Comment: `printf("%c%c\n", argv[1][0], argv[2][0]);` if you execute `./a.out John Smith`. Don't use argv if input by `GetString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't show the definition of `GetString()`, I'm pretty sure you're not calling it correctly, because there's no semicolon after it and you almost certainly do not want to overwrite `argv[0]`. Compiling with debugging symbols (`-g` in GCC) and running in a debugger will tell you which line of code crashed the program.

**Edit:**  My guess is that you're crashing when you try to dereference `argv[i+1]`, which is `argv[1]`, a `NULL` pointer.  But running in a debugger could confirm or disconfirm this.  You seem to be mixing up the syntax to loop through an argument list with the syntax to read a line from standard input.

Comment: Note that the CS50 code is available readily at [CS50.net](https://manual.cs50.net/library/) — all of two source files (`cs50.h` and `cs50.c`) in a zip-file.  It crops up a fair amount on SO.  Obtaining that would allow you to compile and validate your observation about `argv[i+1]`.

Comment: Ah!  First time I'd heard of CS50.  Thought it was something the prof gave as part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It is unorthodox to use `argv[0]` to hold a pointer to the return value from [CS50](https://manual.cs50.net/library/)'s `GetString()` function, though not actually illegal.

You have a syntax error; you've omitted a semicolon after `GetString()`.

With that fixed, your crash-causing problem is in the indexing in the loop; you are indexing `argv[i+1][0]`, but `argv[1]` is a null pointer unless you provided command line arguments and accessing the null pointer is often a crash (so we can tell you didn't provide any command line arguments).

You can demonstrate with:

```
$ ./initial xyz <<< "john smith"
JXXXXXXXXXX
$
```

It didn't crash, and it did repeatedly copy the first letter of the argument converted to upper case (because you keep accessing `argv[i+1][0]`).

The fixes are correspondingly simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    int n = 0;

    string str = GetString();
    printf("%c", toupper(str[0]));
    for (x = 0, n = strlen(str); x < n; x++)
    {
        printf("%c", toupper(str[x]));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example run

```
$ ./initials <<< "john smith"
JJOHN SMITH
$
```

This isn't the required output, but it does show the program working safely and gives you a decent basis from which to work to get the correct answer.